# two-factor authentication does not contain definition for GetEmailConfirmationTokenAsync

Tags: c#, asp.net, two-factor-authentication

I am trying to implement two-factor authentication. In two-factor authentication, I want to generate 6 digit token and this 6 digit token send to user mail id.

Problem is that when I implement Register method in AccountController, I am getting error in this mehtod  **GetEmailConfirmationTokenAsync**.

I install all necessary package Like,

- Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.Owin;
- Microsoft.AspNet.Identity;
- Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.EntityFramework;
- Microsoft.Owin.Security;
- Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.Sample;
- Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.Core

Error : two-factor authentication does not contain definition for GetEmailConfirmationTokenAsync.

I am referring this two link :

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/webdev/archive/2014/02/18/adding-two-factor-authentication-to-an-application-using-asp-net-identity.aspx

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/webdev/archive/2014/02/12/per-request-lifetime-management-for-usermanager-class-in-asp-net-identity.aspx

Code :

```
    public async Task<ActionResult> Register(RegisterViewModel model)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
           //var user = new ApplicationUser() { UserName = model.UserName };

            var user = new ApplicationUser() { UserName = model.UserName, Email = model.Email };

            var result = await UserManager.CreateAsync(user, model.Password);
            //if (result.Succeeded)
            //{
               // await SignInAsync(user, isPersistent: false);
               // return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
            //}


            if (result.Succeeded)
            {
                string code = await UserManager.GetEmailConfirmationTokenAsync(user.Id);
                var callbackUrl = Url.Action("ConfirmEmail", "Account", new { userId = user.Id, code = code }, protocol: Request.Url.Scheme);
                await UserManager.SendEmailAsync(user.Id, "Confirm your account", "Please confirm your account by clicking this link: <a href=\"" + callbackUrl + "\">link</a>");
                return View("ShowEmail");
            }
            else
            {
                AddErrors(result);
            }
        }

        // If we got this far, something failed, redisplay form
        return View(model);
    }
```

Comment: hope you are using the latest asp.net identity 2.0. Check GenerateEmailConfirmationToken http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn497485%28v=vs.108%29.aspx

Comment: Where we can check asp.net identity ?

Comment: I was talking about Microsoft.AspNet.Identity

Comment: http://www.asp.net/identity/overview/features-api/account-confirmation-and-password-recovery-with-aspnet-identity (An example of using these methods from ASP.NET team

Comment: I am using Microsoft ASP.NET Identity Core 2.1.0.

Answer (score 1):

Create empty web application and use package manager console to install following asp.net identity framework sample from NuGet and play around to understand asp.net identity. This sample included end to end sample application which included normal email registration and two-factor authentication which you exactly asking in your question.

Install-Package Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.Samples

Hope this helps.